# Is there anyway i can create an intranet request form and have it be stored in a database?

Tags: database, forms, intranet, microsoft, save

I am trying to create a form for my companies intraNet site. The idea is as follows:

1. An employee wants to make a purchase, so they will go to the appropriate page in the intraNet
2. They will fill out the form on the intraNet page
3. They click the email button
4. The data in the form is saved in a database, and an email is sent to me stating that there is purchase order request form filled out

I am not exactly sure how to go about this. Part of me wants to create it in a Data Access Page but I am not sure that's correct.

If there is no one here who can help, is there anyone who can direct me to someone/something that can help me?

Comment: Okay, just realized that this may be the wrong forum. I apologize for that.

Comment: Make it the same you would do for the inter-net, but just make it available locally? Mail servers would work the same way.

Comment: I can help you make the form itself, and integrate the database. Use the contact form on my homepage (click on my Username for that).

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Database Form Builder for Intranets](http://www.vialect.com/noodle-intranet-software-features/intranet-features-database-form-builder)!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a thing about your systems, we use SharePoint and InfoPath for that.

- A form is built in infopath-
- The form is served up by SharePoint (so it is always the latest version)
- Saved in SharePoint document library
- Data is queried (kinda) like a database in SharePoint
- And email alerts me to new entries on whatever schedule I wish with a SharePoint alert

But this suggestion is making a ton of assumptions:

1. You have a Windows Server that can have SharePoint installed
2. You have InfoPath to use

Neither of those are very trivial, or necessarily free.